# Changing the textview in a different view

Tags: java, android, textview, android-view

I'm trying to prepare a view to be shown by update the text in the textview before I ever switch over to that view.

I've declared the textview variable as public, initialized it in the OnCreate

```
 Info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BackDialogText);
```

And then when it comes time to change the text, I get a nullpointerException

```
Info.setText(TheString);
setContentView(R.layout.mydialog_layout);
```

I've run the app without the setText and it runs fine, showing me my view with the predefined text. Is there some trick I'm missing to update the text of the view?

Comment: Does the textview 'Info' belong to some dialog? Then you will need to use 'Info = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.BackDialogText);'

Comment: It belongs to the mydialog_layout.
So in that case: `mydialog_layout.findViewById(R.id.BackDialogText)`

Comment: Ok. Then read @Vipul Shah's answer. That's correct. It will work. Use setContentView(R.layout.mydialog_layout);
Info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BackDialogText);
Info.setText(TheString);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically before you set the view

```
 setContentView(R.layout.mydialog_layout);
```

to your activity you cannot use the elements inside the view in your code. So you must have something like this in your code

```
setContentView(R.layout.mydialog_layout);
 Info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BackDialogText); // you cannot initialize your view before  setcontentview
 Info.setText(TheString);  //this line must be always called after setContentView
```

Answer (score 1):

Just interchange the line positions.

Below is the working snippet.

```
setContentView(R.layout.mydialog_layout);
Info.setText(TheString);
```

Comment: He says he wants to modify one view from another view.

Comment: This is correct, I just needed to define the TextView after changing views. So the code goes:
`setContentView(R.layout.mydialog_layout);
Info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BackDialogText);
Info.setText(TheString);`

Comment: @AtlasOnEarth Glad to see that.In feature please be clear with your question.so users can understand it and they can propose good solutions.

Answer (score 0):

findViewById() finds Views in the View you're calling it from.

edit: sorry my Mac was crashing and I couldn't expand further.  Basically, in Android only the foreground Activity is living at any one point. So even modifying one View from another Activity is not a good idea. If it's just the text you want to modify, then you have a couple of options, the easiest is to have a public static variable in one of the Activities, and calling setText with that variable.

So for instance:

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {
    private static theString = "";

    public static void setString(String s) { 
         theString = s;
     }

    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
      setContentView(R.layout.mydialog_layout);
    Info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BackDialogText);



      Info.setText(TheString);
    }
}
```

and then in Activity2 you can call:

```
Activity1.setString("New String");
```

Comment: So I would need to find it from the view I'm going to call later? For example `mydialog_layout.findViewById(R.id.BackDialogText)`?